# jquery: change the URL address without redirecting?

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modify Address Bar URL in AJAX App to Match Current State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457/modify-address-bar-url-in-ajax-app-to-match-current-state)

How can I change the URL address without redirecting the page?

For instance, when I click on this link below:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/projects/article-1" class="get-article">link</a>
```

I will grab the URL from the link:

```
var path = object.attr('href');
```

If I do this below, the page will be redirected:

```
window.location = path;
```

I want to do something like this [site](http://www.pentagram.com/work/#/all/all/newest/), when you click on the image, the ajax call will fetch the requested page and the URL address on the window will be changed too, so that it has a path for what you click.

Comment: note that gmail is a better example for what you're looking for

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 83, accepted):

NOTE: `history.pushState()` is now supported - see other answers.

You **cannot** change the whole url without redirecting, what you can do instead is change the **hash**.

The **hash** is the part of the url that goes after the # symbol. That was initially intended to direct you (locally) to sections of your HTML document, but you can read and modify it through javascript to use it *somewhat like a global variable*.

---

If applied well, this technique is useful in two ways:

1. the browser history will remember each different step you took (since the url+hash changed)
2. you can have an address which links not only to a particular html document, but also gives your javascript a clue about what to do. That means you end up pointing to a state inside your web app.

---

**To change the hash you can do:**

```
document.location.hash = "show_picture";
```

---

**To watch for hash changes you have to do something like:**

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
    var what_to_do = document.location.hash;    
    if (what_to_do=="#show_picture")
        show_picture();
}
```

---

Of course the hash is just a string, so you can do pretty much what you like with it. For example you can put a whole object there if you use JSON to *stringify* it.

There are very good JQuery libraries to do advanced things with that.

Comment: Brendan's method works, provided you use same domain.

Comment: Chrome and Safari introduced support `history.pushState()` in 2010, so this answer was not quite correct even when written.  IE is the last major browser to not support `history.pushState()`, and that's expected to change in IE 10.

Answer (score 74):

See here - http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1319992&t=1331393279&page=1#comment11751402

Essentially:

```
history.pushState('data', '', 'http://your-domain/path');
```

You can manipulate the history object to make this work.

It only works on the same domain, but since you're satisfied with using the hash tag approach, that shouldn't matter.

Obviously would need to be cross-browser tested, but since that was posted on the Opera forum I'm safe to assume it would work in Opera, and I just tested it in Chrome and it worked fine.

Comment: IE < 10 does not support this.

Comment: If you don't want to actually change the history and only change URL you should use history.replaceState('data', '', 'http://your-domain/path'); instead

Comment: It comes from  HTML5 API

Answer (score 8):

That site makes use of the "fragment" part of a url: the stuff after the "#". This is not sent to the server by the browser as part of the GET request, but can be used to store page state. So yes you can change the fragment without causing a page refresh or reload. When the page loads, your javascript reads this fragment and updates the page content appropriately, fetching data from the server via ajax requests as required. To read the fragment in js:

```
var fragment = location.hash;
```

but note that this value will include the "#" character at the beginning. To set the fragment:

```
location.hash = "your_state_data";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you ask (and the linked site does not do exactly that either).

You *can*, however, modify the part of the url after the `#` sign, which is called the *fragment*, like this:

```
window.location.hash = 'something';
```

Fragments do **not** get sent to the server (so, for example, Google itself cannot tell the difference between `http://www.google.com/` and `http://www.google.com/#something`), but they can be read by Javascript on your page. In turn, this Javascript can decide to perform a different AJAX request based on the value of the fragment, which is how the site you linked to probably does it.

Answer (score 2):

This is achieved through URL rewriting, not through URL obfuscating, which can't be done.

Another way to do this, as has been mentioned is by changing the hashtag, with

```
window.location.hash = "/2131/"
```

Answer (score 1):

No, because that would open up the floodgates for phishing. The only part of the URI you can change is the fragment (everything after the `#`). You can do so by setting `window.location.hash`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really change the whole URL in the location bar without redirecting (think of the security issues!).

However you can change the `hash` part (whats after the `#`) and read that: `location.hash`

**ps.** prevent the default `onclick` redirect of a link by something like:

```
$("#link").bind("click",function(e){
  doRedirectFunction();
  e.preventDefault();
})
```