# JS/HTML5 remove url params from url

Tags: javascript, html, url, url-parameters

i have an url like this

```
/users/?i=0&p=90
```

how can i remove in js the part from

```
? to 90
```

can any one show me some code?

EDIT

i mean doing this with window.location.href (so in browser url bar directly)

i tryed

```
function removeParamsFromBrowserURL(){
    document.location.href =  transform(document.location.href.split("?")[0]);
    return document.location.href;
}
```

also i would like to not make redirect, so just clean the url from ? to end

Comment: So you just want it to be `/users/90`, or nothing after `/users/`?

Comment: @JonathanSampson i need just /users/

Comment: but not as string i need to do that on browser bar directly

Comment: `document.location.href = transform(document.location.href)`; use any of the below answers for the transform itself.

Comment: see my dit it doesn't works @Amadan

Comment: Errm... I meant more something along the lines of `document.location.href = document.location.href.split("?")[0]` (with `transform` being a metaphorical function indicating one of the answers below - it does not exist)

Comment: ihiih check my edit at the end ;)

Comment: You can't change the URL without redirecting, unless the only thing you're changing is the hash (the thingy after `#`).

Comment: @Amadan can you show me code please ? thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function removeParamsFromBrowserURL(){
    return window.location.href.replace(/\?.*/,'');
}
```

Comment: should be ok but it redirects me

Comment: Of course it redirects. There is no way to do this without the redirect.

Comment: No, this function just returns the "clean" part of the `window.lcoation.href`

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the `/users/` portion:

```
var newLoc = location.href.replace( /\?.+$/, '' );
```

You could also split the string, and return the first portion:

```
var newLoc = location.href.split("?")[0];
```

Or you could match everything up to the question mark:

```
if ( matches = location.href.match( /^(.+)\?/ ) ) {
  alert( matches[1] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is `leftside = whole.split('?')[0]`, assuming there's no ? in the desired left side

http://jsfiddle.net/wjG5U/1/

This will remove ?... from the url and automatically reload the browser to the stripped url (can't get it to work in JSFiddle) I have the code below in a file, and put some ?a=b content manually then clicked the button.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function strip() {
  whole=document.location.href;
  leftside = whole.split('?')[0];
  document.location.href=leftside;
}

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="strip()">Click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm no expert, but I believe these guys :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/6478682/1325290 no way without redirecting :(

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the /users/ portion, then you could just substring it:

```
var url = users/?i=0&p=90;
var urlWithNoParams = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('?') - 1);
```

That extracts the string from index 0 to the character just before the '?' character.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with #page back and forth referrals sticking in the url no matter which url redirect I used. This solved everything.

I used the script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function strip() {
  whole=document.location.href;
  leftside = whole.split('#')[0];
  document.location.href=leftside;
}
</script>
<a onclick="strip()" href="http://[mysite]/hent.asp" >Click here</a>
```