# Update current URL with extra parameters

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a products page which displays 10 products on each page.

The `GET` variable `&perpage=10` changes the amount of results.
I've made a `<select>` dropdown to choose different amounts of results.

Whenever this selection box is changed, `&perpage=NEWVALUE` should be added to the **current** URL.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only ways to *modify* the current URL is with hashtags (`#`) and [`window.history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history), both of which don't actually reload the page. These methods *do* dispatch change-events that you could listen-for and, using ajax, re-query a backend script to get results, however - this may be a bit more than what you actually need.

What you'll want to do, most likely, is have your form (with the select-menu) re-submit the form back to the current page. Something like:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <select name="perpage" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Slight correction on this - cross-browser you are correct - but you *can* modify the URL without a refresh or a #hashtag in Webkit browsers by using `window.history.replaceState`. It is a contested feature though so only a minute grumble :) Perfectly correct other than that.

Comment: @pebbl, correct - but it's also the same as using a `#` in the regards that it doesn't actually re-query the page; it only replaces the browser's history of the current page. Navigating "back" to it will work, but not during the current instance.

Comment: yep, I know, it was just because you stated *'the only way'* that my critique voice kicked in... what you state is utterly correct.

Comment: @pebbl You win this round, and again are correct =P; I've updated my wording to include `window.history.replaceState` as well =] ..Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Well, just `location.href += "&perpage="+newvalue` (with appropriately-defined `newvalue` from the `<select>` value) would work, but after a while you'll get something like

```
http://example.com/products.php?perpage=10&perpage=20&perpage=50&perpage=10&perpage=5&perpage=20&................
```

So you really should do something more like:

```
location.href = location.href.replace(/([?&])perpage=\d+/,"$1perpage="+newvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href="?perpage=NEWVALUE"
```

This will append the query string to the current location and the window will navigate to it

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, JavaScript?

```
<form method="get">
    <select name="perpage">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Using the `GET` method will post the `perpage` value to your url, and it will reload your page (set your `action="someurl"` if you want it to go to another page).

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a URL like you describe without reloading the page. (Assuming you don't want to reload the page)

See [jquery: change the URL address without redirecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478485/jquery-change-the-url-address-without-redirecting) for a more complete explanation, and how to do some something similar with a hash.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking how to do this on the server side (your question doesn't state), here's one way to do what you want:

```
$parts = parse_url($url); # parse the URL into its component parts
if (isset($parts['query'])) {
    parse_str($parts['query'], $qs); # split query string into parts
} else {
    $qs = array();
}
$qs['perpage'] = $NEWVALUE; # add param to array
$parts['query'] = http_build_query($qs); # build query string from array

# then, using `unparse_url()` from 
# http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#106731
# you rebuild the URL:

$url = unparse_url($parts);

# For reference, here's `unparse_url()`:

function unparse_url($parsed_url) { 
  $scheme   = isset($parsed_url['scheme']) ? $parsed_url['scheme'] . '://' : '';
  $host     = isset($parsed_url['host']) ? $parsed_url['host'] : ''; 
  $port     = isset($parsed_url['port']) ? ':' . $parsed_url['port'] : ''; 
  $user     = isset($parsed_url['user']) ? $parsed_url['user'] : ''; 
  $pass     = isset($parsed_url['pass']) ? ':' . $parsed_url['pass']  : ''; 
  $pass     = ($user || $pass) ? "$pass@" : ''; 
  $path     = isset($parsed_url['path']) ? $parsed_url['path'] : ''; 
  $query    = isset($parsed_url['query']) ? '?' . $parsed_url['query'] : ''; 
  $fragment = isset($parsed_url['fragment']) ? '#' . $parsed_url['fragment'] : '';
   return "$scheme$user$pass$host$port$path$query$fragment"; 
}
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#106731

Comment: It looks to me like you've answered a different question to what the OP was asking. The server-side part is already functioning, it's the front-end posting/getting of the value they are having difficulties with.