# Show/Hide div during existing script

Tags: javascript, css, html, web

I have an existing script that performs a function on my website when a button is pressed. Is there a way to make this button also show a div at the same time? When you visit the google homepage you are met with this;
[image]
Yet when you press google search you are met with this;
[image]

I know this is a different page with a different url but is there a way to achieve this with show/hide div? I am not bothered about people disabling javascript because that is required for my system anyway!

Comment: Why can't you add code to show/hide a div to your existing code? What is it about your existing code that prevents you from just adding in that extra functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: [jquery: change the URL address without redirecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478485/jquery-change-the-url-address-without-redirecting)

```
document.location.hash = "show_picture";
```

Javascript can only control the stuff after *#*, that is also what google does. With this line you reset the stuff behind the *#*

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to get what you want and put the following code in button click event

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
</body>
</html>
```