# How to change the url value once the user select an option from the dropdown

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, django

Hi project works on Django framework, with some AngularJS part. One of the function of my website is once the user selects any option from the dropdown the url of the website changes. Anyone have any idea how to do? is there any angularJS function for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean 'the url of the website changes'? The url of the current page, without reloading it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery: change the URL address without redirecting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478485/jquery-change-the-url-address-without-redirecting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $location is you do not want to actually navigate.

[$Location documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

If you do want to navigate you can use:
$window.location.href

Comment: HI Blake, awesome. That's the one I want. But am encountering an issue here. So I tried like this, `$location.path($scope.final_data.mydata);`.  But it returned like `loader/#/bobbie`. Means there is an extra '#' there. How to get rid off that and display the url as  `loader/bobbie`?