# window.onbeforeunload....alert to restrict when refresh button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, alert, jquery-events

I have security problem that when user  leave\close the window before logout, I want to show an alert message.

So that I did this:

```
window.onbeforeunload   = function(){  return " confirm msg";}
```

I get the alert, but now the problem is,
if I click refresh button the default operation is to run without the alert message.

I got the answer for a keyboard but not for a mouse click.
Can any one help me,
with how to detect when the user clicks the refresh button?

If you have any suggestion please post...

Comment: Does not seem to be `php` related...

Comment: check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247743/detect-browser-refresh-in-javascript/3247977#3247977

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way you can tell if the `onbeforeunload` event is triggered by a refresh, close, etc.