# Logout webpage when click on refresh button

Tags: javascript, refresh, logout

I am developing a website. Where I need to logout the page when one try to refresh the page.

I got the code for logout when one click on `f5` for refresh and also I got the code for disable `right click` on the page. but I dont know how to prevent the refresh button of browser or logout when I press refresh button. I searched many sites. But didn't get an answer.

The code I gor for `F5` key is

```
function fkey(e){
    e = e || window.event;
   if( wasPressed ) return; 

    if (e.keyCode == 116) {
         alert("f5 pressed");
        wasPressed = true;
    }else {
        alert("Window closed");
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me for the issue with refresh button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect Browser Refresh in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247743/detect-browser-refresh-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work

```
$("*").keypress(function(e)
{
if (e.keyCode == 116) {
     e.preventDefault();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    //call logout process here
}
```

onbeforeunload  is an event that fires when a window is about to unload its resources. The document is still visible and the event is still cancelable, in other words, whenever you refresh or close a page it fires an event 'onbeforeunload'. When this event returns a non-void value, the user is prompted to confirm the page unload. In most browsers, the return value of the event is displayed in this dialog.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    //call logout process here
}
```

Any custom declaration on OnBeforeUnload will not be executed as the support is removed from the code. So, the above solution will not work for Chrome.
Instead, use HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);